# how can find number of path component?

Tags: general-topology

In metric topology, I learn about $\mathbb R$ is not topological equivalent to $\mathbb R$$^2$ using contradiction for restriction function.

In other words, I will prove that the path components of the domain and codomain for the given function are different.
$f\colon$ $\mathbb R$ $\setminus \{a\}$ $\to$ $\mathbb R^2$ $ \setminus$ $\{f(a)\}$

here are the Question
$\mathbb 1$. how can I find number of path component?
: In the previous problem, my professer was only explained through illustrations. So I don't know how can find number of path component. which means |$\mathbb R^2$ $ \setminus$ $\{f(a)\}$|$=$$1$ and |$\mathbb R$ $\setminus \{a\}$|$=$$2$.

I think to find the number of path components, I need to find the path function(conti map), right?
If yes, how would I go about finding it in the given problem?

$2$. my homework is showing that $\mathbb R$ is not topological equivalent to $\mathbb R$$^n$
I want to solve it in a similar way as before which means how can prove |$\mathbb R^n$ $ \setminus$ $\{f(a)\}$|$\neq$$|\mathbb R$ $\setminus \{a\}|$?

plz give me answer.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The" way to show $\Bbb R\setminus\{a\}$ has two path components is to notice that $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ form a topological disconnection so there must be at least two (path) components, and then to notice the intervals like $(-\infty,a)$ are clearly path connected.

The simplest (in the sense of not requiring much experience with topology) way to show $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$ (for any $x$) is path connected is to write down explicit paths. There are multiple ways of doing this, I'm sure.

Express $x=(u,v)$ and say we want to connect the point $(a,b)$ to the point $(c,d)$ in $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$. Suppose $b\neq v$ and $c\neq u$. Then the rectangular path that takes $(a,b)$ to $(c,b)$ in a horizontal straight line and $(c,b)$ to $(c,d)$ in a vertical straight line will work, and has an explicit formula. If $c=u$ or $b=v$ then we can do the same thing in the case $a\neq u$ and $d\neq v$. If this also fails then wlog we suppose the points are $(u,b)$ and $(u,d)$ where $b,d\neq v$. These are easy to connect explicitly; join $(u,b)\sim(u+1,b)\sim(u+1,d)\sim(u,d)$ in straight line paths.

One general, slick way to see $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{x\}$ is path-connected for any $x$ and $n\ge2$ is to observe it deformation retracts onto a unit sphere centred at $x$ and then to observe $S^{n-1}$ is path connected when $n\ge2$ - and why is that? Well, $S^{n-1}$ is the closure of some subspace homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, which is connected - hence $S^{n-1}$ is connected - and $S^{n-1}$ is also locally path-connected (I have used the stereographic projection twice here) hence $S^{n-1}$ is also globally path-connected.

Comment: @Imnau welcome to the site